# Jquery Masked Input doesn't call the function mask()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I spent 6 hours researching but I have no clue it it doesn't recognize function mask() although I'm 100% sure that I included Jquery and the plugin extension already.

I tried using online script, offline script but none of them seems to work. Eventhough I downloaded the whole things from the plugin official website and add all of them to my page it still doesn't recognize the function mask().

Please help. Thanks in advance.

I don't think any wrong with the script. I wrote an extremely simple script to test the code:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#phone_input').mask("0000-0000", {
                    placeholder: "XXXX-XXXX"
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form><input type="text" id="phone_input" name="phone" /></form>
    </body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: works just fine for me... check your browsers network tab to see whether there is any error

Comment: Have you tried the code yet? It doesn't work for me. I tested on IE, Chrome and FF.  It doesn't work at all.

Comment: Yes, I tried it.... copied the code as given to a file and checked it is not giving any error

Comment: did you put some numbers into the fields to see if it works?

Comment: Can you try by "$(document).ready(function($)" instead "$(document).ready(function()" because example in their site showing should have '$'  as a parameter.